# Returning IS NOT NULL in SQL CASE WHEN expression

Tags: sql-server, case, where-clause

How can I return IS NOT NULL on from a SQL Server `CASE` statement?

I have tried something like this:

```
WHERE 
    a.BillToCustomerID IS NOT NULL
    AND CASE @taxSchedRequiered
           WHEN 1 THEN a.TaxScheduleID IS NOT NULL
        END
```

but it is not working for me.

**Update**

I need to filter by a.TaxScheduleID IS NOT NULL, just in the specific case when the value of the variable @taxSchedRequiered (possible values are: null, 0, 1) is 1.

Comment: Your question is not very clear.  Perhaps this can point you in the right direction anyway:  `where 'TRUE' = case when @taxSchedRequired = 1 and a.TaxScheduleID is not null then 'TRUE' else 'FALSE' end and a.BillToCustomerID is not null`

Comment: What do you want to do?

Comment: `CASE` in T-SQL is an **expression** (like `a+b` - **not** a statement) that can return one, atomic value (from several possible values) - but you **cannot** use `CASE` to conditionally/optionally add/run code snippets like you're trying to do.....

Comment: Just search "case in where clause"

Comment: @avery_larry you are right, I edit the question, trying to be more clear.

Answer (score 1):

just change the logic and use an OR

```
WHERE 
    a.BillToCustomerID IS NOT NULL
    AND (@taxSchedRequiered <> 1 OR a.TaxScheduleID IS NOT NULL)
```

this will include all records if `@taxSchedRequiered = 0` else it will only include records that have a `a.TaxScheduleID <> NULL`

Also make sure that `@taxSchedRequired` has a value other than `NULL` when you execute this

**Edit to check for null param**

```
WHERE 
    a.BillToCustomerID IS NOT NULL
    AND (ISNULL(@taxSchedRequiered,0) = 0 OR a.TaxScheduleID IS NOT NULL)
```

Comment: the variable taxSchedRequiered will just tell me if I have to filter by a.TaxScheduleID IS NOT NULL, or not.

Comment: @jczmog above should do that